is it possible to embed a Facebook post through website user inputting its share link?
I just want the website user to input a link of a post on his Facebook page, and show this post as an embedded post in his session html, but Facebook android 'Share' button gives links like: https://www.facebook.com/share/uixYeGcfc6SxrndV/?mibextid=xfxF2i
which does not work in this:
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v19.0&appId=675957057529080" nonce="IvtyecK8"></script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="**fore-mentioned link**" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"></div>

but this link works if used in above block of code: https://fb.watch/rFSSa76OLh/
so, is there any solution?
thanks in advance..

this is the message appears: 'This Facebook post is no longer available. It may have been removed or the privacy settings of the post may have changed.'


The URL that the first example you've given redirects me to, https://www.facebook.com/100064844826300/posts/845421794295974/?rdid=5OgL6015WRYIZ4aU, appears to work. But Facebook has measures in place against "bots" trying to follow these redirects, so you will likely have a hard time, if you attempted to gets this second URL via code.

@CBroe , first, thanks.     so, there is no simple way..
